# android sending mail using javamail smtp giving authenticationfailure

Tags: android, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using javamail and smtp . It worked for me when I was sending from my gmail address. I changed the same code to send from my exchange account and it is not working. I am getting authentication failure exception.

**Code**

```
public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
private String mailhost = "smtp.company.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GmailSender(String user, String password) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "com.example.javamailtestpreetha.AlwaysTrustSSLContextFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

     session = Session.getInstance(props, new GMailAuthenticator(user, password));
   // session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}
```

I tried with default port i.e. 25 , and that time I got the error indicating wrong port number. So I assume the port number is right. I tried ping host and its working. The user name I tried `domain/username, username, username@company.com` . But got the same exception always. Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance

I  set debugging on and got the following logs. It is telling incorrect authentication data . I am sure my login and password is correct. Can anyone help me on how to enter the username?

Is it `username` or `domain\username` or `domain/username` or `username@mycompanyaddress.com` or anything else? I suspect this could be an issue.

I tried with  adding `props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");` but failing with same **error**

---

> 01-29 17:50:46.958: I/System.out(3898): 220-mycompany.servername.com
>   ESMTP Exim 4.80 #2 Tue, 29 Jan 2013 16:50:51 +0300  01-29
>   17:50:46.958: I/System.out(3898): 220-We do not authorize the use of
>   this system to transport unsolicited,  01-29 17:50:46.958:
>   I/System.out(3898): 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 01-29 17:50:46.962:
>   I/System.out(3898): DEBUG SMTP: connected to host
>   "smtp.mail.mycompany.com", port: 465 01-29 17:50:46.962:
>   I/System.out(3898): EHLO localhost 01-29 17:50:46.989:
>   I/StatusBarPolicy(218): onSignalStrengthsChanged 01-29 17:50:47.220:
>   I/System.out(3898): 250-mycompany.servername.com Hello localhost
>   [80.227.5.70] 01-29 17:50:47.220: I/System.out(3898): 250-SIZE
>   52428800 01-29 17:50:47.220: I/System.out(3898): 250-8BITMIME 01-29
>   17:50:47.220: I/System.out(3898): 250-PIPELINING 01-29 17:50:47.220:
>   I/System.out(3898): 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 01-29 17:50:47.220:
>   I/System.out(3898): 250 HELP 01-29 17:50:47.224: I/System.out(3898):
>   DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800" 01-29 17:50:47.224:
>   I/System.out(3898): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
>   01-29 17:50:47.224: I/System.out(3898): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension
>   "PIPELINING", arg "" 01-29 17:50:47.228: I/System.out(3898): DEBUG
>   SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN" 01-29 17:50:47.228:
>   I/System.out(3898): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg "" 01-29
>   17:50:47.228: I/System.out(3898): DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
>   01-29 17:50:47.228: I/System.out(3898): AUTH LOGIN 01-29 17:50:47.552:
>   I/System.out(3898): 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 01-29 17:50:47.552:
>   I/System.out(3898): ZmZoY1xwc3VyYWo= 01-29 17:50:48.404:
>   I/StatusBarPolicy(218): onSignalStrengthsChanged 01-29 17:50:49.806:
>   I/System.out(3898): 535 Incorrect authentication data**

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on [session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  Perhaps the protocol trace will provide more clues.

If you're using Exchange 2007, you may be running into the AUTH=PLAIN bug described on the [JavaMail wiki](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/pages/Exchange).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my que with debug logs. Tried the plain auth disable but didnt work . Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using Exchange, so I wouldn't expect that to work.  From the debug output, it appears to be failing after asking for your username and before asking for your password.  That suggests that you're giving it a bad username.  Your server administrator should be able to tell you what form of username to use.  Can you connect to the same mail server using another mail client, such as Thunderbird?

Comment: I checked and it seems the smtp is disabled for the server . Can that give this error ? . I had tried giving username in all combinations, but always same error

Comment: Possible, I suppose, but if SMTP is disabled I don't know why it's accepting SMTP connections at all.